# Python Flask MongoDB default column

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine

I have a small Flask API connected on a MongoDB database, using MongoEngine as ORM.

One of my documents it's something like this:

```
class PriceHistoryDocument(db.EmbeddedDocument):
    create_date=db.DateTimeField(required=True, default=get_current_date())
    price=db.DecimalField(required=True, precision=4)
    error=db.StringField(required=True, default='')

class ProductModel(AuditModel):
    meta = {'collection': 'product', 'queryset_class': CustomQuerySet}
    id = db.SequenceField(primary_key=True)
    price_history = db.EmbeddedDocumentListField(PriceHistoryDocument)
```

**get_current_date():**

```
from datetime import datetime
def get_current_date():
    return datetime.utcnow()
```

And the save product part from the controller:

```
    try:
        product = ProductModel.objects.get(url=url)
        # current_app.logger.info(f'Product url found {url}')
        product.price_history.append(current_price_detail)
        product.save()
        if response: # TODO: fix this to something clearer
            updated_url.append(url)
        else:
            failed_url.append(url)
    except Exception as e:
        # current_app.logger.info('Unable to save the product details {e}!')
        failed_url.append(url)
```

My problem is if i start the server and call the controller multiple time, everytime the product is saved in DB with the same date (the date when server was started).

The same is if i change the **create_date** field with **default=datetime.utcnow()**

Why is that ?

LE:
Figure it out:
the default value should not call the function, need just a reference

```
create_date=db.DateTimeField(required=True, default=get_current_date)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python there is a difference between code that runs "at import time" and code that runs during "runtime" (after all imports are done).

Your usage of `default=get_current_date()` runs at import time, that is when the program starts. So at runtime, it just always uses the value that was already determined at import time, which was the time your server program started.

What you might want, is to use the `get_current_date` as a callable. To do that use `default=get_current_date` without the parentheses. This way at runtime the function will be called each time a default value is required, and it will then do what you really wanted in the first place.